# Cyclic dependency in HttpInterceptor using nested service

Tags: angular

i have the following three services: `AuthConfigService`, `AuthService` and `TokenService`.

The `AuthConfigService` constructor fetches OIDC metadata from the OIDC discovery endpoint and later provides them to the `AuthService` and `TokenService`. Both the `AuthService` and `TokenService` reference the `AuthConfigService` in their constructor.

```
// AuthConfigService
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  this.fetch_oidc_metadata(); // does http call to discovery endpoint
}

// AuthService, TokenService
constructor(private auth_config_service: AuthConfigService) {}
```

Now i tried to introduce an Interceptor to automatically set the `Authorization`-Header when requests are made to a specific endpoint (like shown here https://angular.io/guide/http-interceptor-use-cases).

```
// AuthInterceptor
constructor(private auth_service: AuthService) {}
```

But i get a cyclic dependency error, between my `AuthInterceptor`, the `AuthService` and the `AuthConfigService`.
I found this github issue (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18224) which is sort of the same problem. In my case the problem lies within the nested `AuthConfigService`, because the reqeust isn't made in the injected AuthService directly, but in the nested (`AuthConfigService`). Therefore their proposed solution doesen't seem not to work.

If i just merge the `AuthConfigService` functionality into the `AuthService` i have another cyclic dependency between `AuthService` and `TokenService`, because the `TokenService` has to call the `AuthService` to get the token endpoint.

A workaround would be not to use the OIDC discovery endpoint at all, but specify the required endpoints in the environment. But this would require the user to provide multiple values, rather then just a single OIDC url. (For the sake of discussion, let's say this workaround won't be acceptable)

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a factory-based solution:

```
function createAuthConfig(app_config: AppConfig, http: HttpClient) {
  const metadata = http.get<OpenIDMetadata>(app_config.auth_config.discovery_endpoint);
  return new AuthConfigService(app_config, metadata);
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
  deps: [APP_CONFIG_SERVICE, HttpClient],
  useFactory: (createAuthConfig)
})
export class AuthConfigService {
  constructor(app_config: AppConfig, metadata: Observable<...>) {
    this.metadata = metadata;
    ...
  }
}
```

By specifying `deps` inside the `@Injectable`, `APP_CONFIG_SERVICE` and `HttpClient` are injected into the factory-function. The factory-function does the http request and passes the result-Observable into the `AuthConfigService` constructor.